# How to change jQuery progressbar status on changed PHP variable?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, progress-bar

Idea is to update progressbar value when PHP variable changes:

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
       $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
          value: <?php echo $_SESSION['value'] ?>
       });
    });
 </script>
```

I tried:

```
    <?php 
        $_SESSION['value'] = 10; 
            sleep(2);
        $_SESSION['value'] = 30;
            sleep(2);
        $_SESSION['value'] = 50;
            sleep(2);
        $_SESSION['value'] = 70;
            sleep(2);
        $_SESSION['value'] = 90;        
    ?>
```

but progressbar is set to last variable `90` only. I want it to continuously update for five times as the value of the variable changes.

Is it possible to do this with jQuery and PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible but only using AJAX as javascript doesn't have access to the PHP session.

The javascript only runs once the PHP file has finished executing which is why you're only seeing it update with the last value.

JS:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("currentProgress.php", function(data) {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
          value: data
        });
    });
}, 1000); // updates every second
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
    // work out the current progress of whatever you're checking on
    echo $value;
?>
```

**Update:** Maybe this is more what you're after: http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script - it can be easily modified to include the jQuery progress bar.

Comment: I wil work with session?  `echo $_SESSION['value'];`

Comment: Yes, in the php file you could write `echo $_SESSION['value'];` and it would update. However, it won't work with your current php file as it will still only print the final value (90).

Comment: I ceated file currentProgress.php and add code `<?php session_start();

echo $_SESSION['value']; ?>` but progress bar still not updating, what can be wrong ?

Comment: It's not updating because you have to change the value of `$_SESSION['value'];`. What is the progress bar showing the progress of?

Comment: but I'm updating in `bar.php` with session

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` exists only on the server-side, so before your browser even receives the response, it will go through all the five stages. The value that will be transmitted is `90`.

If you want to monitor a server-side process you will have to use a different approach, e.g. via ajax.